# How to get a result of a function from another function?

Tags: java

First method:

```
public void Calculate (int a, int b) {
    int sum =a+b;
}
```

Second method:

```
public int getResult(){
    return sum ;
}
```

Comment: Call the function and store it in a variable..?

Comment: `sum` is a local variable in `Calculate()` , you can't access it in `getResult()`

Comment: This makes no sense.. Or maybe you want to store `sum` as a class member variable.

Comment: Please format the code properly first. Secondly, you cannot access local variable `sum` of method `Calculate()` in method `getResult()`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
class xyz {
    int sum;
    public void Calculate(int a, int b) {
        sum = a + b;
    }
    public int getResult() {
        return sum;
    }
}
```

Comment: Please format so that the reply is readable and really helpful to someone.

Answer (score 5):

It's not entirely clear what you want to do here, but it seems like you have two options...

You can store the value in a class-level variable:

```
private int sum = 0;
public void Calculate (int a, int b) {
    sum = a + b;
}
public int getResult() {
    return sum;
}
```

Or, probably more effectively, just return the value from the function which calculates it:

```
public int Calculate (int a, int b) {
    return a + b;
}
```

Unless there's a particularly good reason otherwise, it's usually better to just do the simplest thing possible.  Which in this case is just to add the numbers and return the result.  Otherwise consuming code will need to remember to always call `Calculate()` *before* calling `getResult()` and will create a dependency on the order of operations when using the object.

Answer (score 4):

```
1. public int Calculate (int a, int b) {
int sum = a + b;
return sum;
}

2.
public int getResult(){ 
return sum = Calculate(15,12);

}
```

Or Try this
 1. public int Calculate (int a, int b) {
    int sum =a+b;
    return sum;
    }

```
2.public int getResult(int a, int b){ 
return sum =Calculate(a,b);

}
```

Comment: This will return sum of 15+12 always i.e 27

Comment: yes, thanks for correcting me, i was going to edit this. I realized it as soon as i post the answer

Comment: Also it makes no sense to have two methods `calculate` (<-lower case name remember) and `getResult` if both result the same value `a+b` and also reassign the same variable `sum`

Answer (score 3):

Your variable is loacalized to only calculate. You can either call calulate it self or in my oppinon globalize the vaiable

```
Class calculate {
     int sum;
        public void calculate(int a, int b) {
        sum =a+b;
        }

        public int getResult(){
         return sum ;
        }
}
```

Comment: You should wrap this code in a class declaration and also change `calculate` method name in lowercase (conventions)

Comment: Done @Gaël That helped!